# how to notify when number of list view changed?

Tags: android, kotlin, listview

I want to check if my list view is empty or not, and then do something
so I need something like `ListView.setOnItemChangeListener`

I tried this [CustomListAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28823703/9348912)
but this only fired in adding item ( it also fires two time each time )

is there any listener to do that

Comment: @Jorn fixed the link

Comment: @Jorn  no idea??